# Array in a While

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

I try to code a API Connection to Shopware (Shop CMS). Now I want to get the Data from a Database and fill the array with it.

So the Original Example Code from the

```
$updateArticle = array(
   'configuratorSet' => array(
        'groups' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'Size',
                'options' => array(
                    array('name' => 'S'),
                    array('name' => 'M'),
                    array('name' => 'L'),
                    array('name' => 'XL'),
                    array('name' => 'XXL'),
                )
            ),
```

Now i want to replace this

```
array('name' => 'S'),
array('name' => 'M'),
array('name' => 'L'),
array('name' => 'XL'),
array('name' => 'XXL'),
```

with a while so like this (but this doesn't work)

```
$updateArticle = array(
   'configuratorSet' => array(
        'groups' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'Farbe',
                'options' => array(

                if ($resultatfarben = $db->query('SELECT * FROM cache_article WHERE artikelnummer = '.$herstellnummer.' GROUP BY farben')) {
                  while($datenfarben = $resultatfarben->fetch_object() ){
                array('name' => ''.$datenfarben->farbe.''),

                  }  
                }
                )
            ),
```

I can't insert a while but I like the same result like the original example in the front of the post but with a mysql while and not write the code by my self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to create the options array with the results of the database. Then, assign this array to the `'options'` property of your `$updateArticle` array

```
$options = array(); // Initialize a new array
$resultatfarben = $db->query('SELECT * FROM cache_article WHERE artikelnummer = '.$herstellnummer.' GROUP BY farben');
while($datenfarben = $resultatfarben->fetch_object() ){
    $ret = array('name' => $datenfarben->farbe);
    $options[] = $ret; // Push each db result ($ret array) in the options array
}

$updateArticle = array(
   'configuratorSet' => array(
        'groups' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'Farbe',
                'options' => $options // Assign the $options array created before
            )
        )
    )
)
```